# Jump to a Byobu window by number

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, byobu

Let's say I have a dozen windows open in Byobu, I am currently on window 2 and I want to go see what's going on in window 9.

How to quickly jump to another window, without having to press <kbd>F4</kbd> seven times?

The best would be some kind of shortcut like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All GNU Screen's keys binding work exactly the same in byobu.

To [select a window](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Select.html#Select), simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>Window number</kbd>

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is conflict with GNU Emacs keys binding, so `byobu` will ask you to chose the behavior.

In any case, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd> to go to beginning of line in Emacs keys binding mode.

Comment: For completeness, if you configured Byobu to use `ctrl`+`a` = go to beginning of line (Emacs style), then you can use `F12` + `1`, `2`, ... to jump to each window by number.

Comment: Is it possible to reach window 10, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to reach any window by either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd> followed by the number and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is unclear: does (Ctrl)+(A) followed by apostrophe take the user to window #10, or does the user still need to type “```10```” and (Enter)?

Comment: Sorry. I was sort of trying to answer one of the comments as well. Ctrl+a followed by a number works for 0 through 9, but 10 jumps to 1. But Ctrl+a, ' 10 or Ctrl+a, w 10 works.

You can use the apostrophe or w followed by the number but it isn't necessary for the lower numbers.